# What is the difference between the keybase.io keyserver gpg key and the one from the fingerprint?

Tags: gnupg, keybase

I did:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv  222B85B0F90BE2D24CFEB93F47484E50656D16C7
sudo apt-key export 222B85B0F90BE2D24CFEB93F47484E50656D16C7 > ~/keybase_apt_key.gpp
wget https://keybase.io/docs/server_security/code_signing_key.asc
vimdiff <(cat keybase_apt_key.gpg| gpg --list-packets --verbose) <(cat code_signing_key.asc| gpg --list-packets --verbose
```

And the one downloaded from the website has 4 more packets in it.  Why does the keyserver one contain 4 fewer packets and how do I tell what's in those 4 extra subpackets?  It's the same pkey in both of them.

Here's the diff.  It doesn't seem to contain any information about the packets.

```
~ ??? /usr/bin/diff -urN <(cat keybase_apt_key.gpg| gpg --list-packets --verbose) <(cat code_signing_key.gpg| gpg --list-packets --verbose)                                                                 ?
gpg: armor header: Comment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org
--- /proc/self/fd/11    2019-09-14 23:08:38.961637960 -0500
+++ /proc/self/fd/12    2019-09-14 23:08:38.961637960 -0500
@@ -20,7 +20,15 @@
        hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
        subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 47484E50656D16C7)
        data: 08DB8F568D5F71F615B6D3CE4AB5140AE14FFBF58F01A83AF0D495BD974A29A4F6759FA6519E949E977D48B9C0BC36EA450390322B82AEC4C35E8F928B17691AA9D83395CBAF480EA7A50932467A2113F3D608310983F184F038AACCC431EF20FFEEB429F08D1A23D897D122423EAA21BB260D5450446A670B9FEB436C7E14D23BAB3EEB802AD4521B18F38671223CCD614E06D0BFC035158DC83C29407D79
4E2B545623CA574967C9171FA14F465847E992048C0B85FA1BBE2A7AC8B33A238EC831D2D3CE2D0E45AB600C8124E551EE1EC703BE0BA455E96602A97776AE0E86C9D8B13D86D38AFA2FC2AC6BA0CA63463C4294068D65C5716A7ADBC7FF5E1165DEF686868D6747131C69FBE0A6224006B74B99297A5831305C562FEF3A33994FFA2E5FE02CB1007024935F7F892E0AA08546D1D825D34C07F69C3EE814E129EE9D7EB15C80
3CC84DEFA4FE96B5556BD399EDE60DC08513A7754718A940448D2442F02CD381FE3CD38AFD2D9EF358674EA323D4CA57BDF270E91B4297E027FA522B00E262391C59BF4B438309BFBB60D9195E282CD0571AE727AA35CC063D5F35C77B143704890E825D6BE624418D16C683D2D2AD1124D1FDDCE403337AE37AB3774725515F8DD53503DAAF8B1C0F902A4FDE9C196B3E05B755010BFCE30AD2E80E325985072E34D3C7D91B
E92DF3804BA3FDCAA72DED332EDF2DB16EBE55A958
-# off=1153 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=574
+# off=1153 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=546
+:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 63847B4B83930F0C
+       version 4, created 1384876995, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
+       digest algo 2, begin of digest c3 59
+       hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2013-11-19)
+       critical hashed subpkt 3 len 4 (sig expires after 4y1d0h0m)
+       subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 63847B4B83930F0C)
+       data: 8E4AEDD840E90D22399784C3C55AD49407EFA4B5F871EC64A6781CC5C7A04825CD54F8A7E9BB80ABEEDA594D093E93895C9AB0AC666901125803C38BD643884E9ECFBF2FB64ACA3D7F5F26A500C66E2E8BF364BE84F0C53B07270B7E2D9BBCFFDB35BD09926F9EEB64FE833B8F7528C7CB645492BE4E7DED9CBE7CC5734723CD03F239FA0E91207AF0E38CE8300031BB7BC59B3B89EC7488EC6535263110EB
30F7E081887B8B534F219EFE0F9717D888DA2E05B81E0C4981FEE78C42957CB8AC0DEB9AD4615D141D8D10854D5313080175D7BF0F58A8D9F2CB856871C4B2BE9360F92A96FA7C74DB540BD1116CA383DDC9711AA20F4BD9AB213EE2DE98F418DCD672A4A87033EF4BE2BB1BAC0814B7CCEC072276AD39ABF4BCE9573BAEC935C7463BE1C7BF7FB8294790BEAB2011F58C7EF778F268DE67BB14F56865AB4589C9E7942364D1
C517A2A016B2E4871FCAC061DACFC6EAB2CA1AE8892BB4638B1C24AC93C00DB0A82212428AFA9D4CC006D478103796A7E970DF61E9B010224244AF104C8FD4C0D55DB7BA7CE2A7180DA82B5A213B7C1F0C1BDF297974552FDE11398DCF0816DC5ACE6514820D99A6875CE04631BFD14E1F448F13415B0CA27C8B14918B944D4127CC7F02B5D6FF75CABDF32FF8EC97DA2F16CC7A90B61346CCC45653B670DB85751B5F3A2781
8E5FD7CD241431CE07E509B4A2FB0D4805B39566DD
+# off=1702 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=574
 :signature packet: algo 1, keyid 47484E50656D16C7
        version 4, created 1510590761, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
        digest algo 2, begin of digest f8 4a
@@ -34,13 +42,39 @@
        hashed subpkt 9 len 4 (key expires after 13y360d0h29m)
        subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 47484E50656D16C7)
        data: 0F4BD21068D80DF0E4B240DF8D46F7C9A30BA6F667E9C1A5AB63830974BEC4E48749A01AAEF7CF670C10C1BEE21FA0BC38314789A396E71D6E84C3F6D54FCF4ADAFC1F873E9806F5FE0FE6B3B5448024CCF21C08B4B552D0EA254932122A35C51599ACE2F6157455342101EE08C029CCA0B4167B71F8C4AF75EA8F398FC485F4F8BAA5CEA41A4866C04125CC3D03209C648B4B5E9453A0CAC6F99273625478
29B6C56CDDA84CADCBB467B7357B2F8626A7AF4EBDE37F1EEC66720E1F36964AA710A906BF0D11CB44B67715717B3002116EC8CB4EC55C32A5C55C23F9A7180B007A276D2C5E76FBB12E83EB3D2F162308B83D8894031200DAACF6D046E813A89064A5CF2A6E598555E94240786D4A3B257C456EDAD4F8EFE242B9E3E85ACDA316DB3508E13780F25D21BA679F4AD7DBD5E2487CDC902964649508D259A17414F53BEA2ED8EE
D9537C791EB9306972B2E1F7C626604A737410BDC08E154F7635DBA54084D168C9528D855FC167330881FF3EF06865CE142918A3A900D886EF8CE37CCE97F7A95CC72A8A17585A127F091DF73E1558CE74A5EEE46D06F34B84F5E324CAB8D8B5F868D65C6CFE575B3C621C2392CA56DA7B58F38B550A1DC62206DBE17D2D1AAAF7FE801F5A7605FB4E4026FE2ACC3C8CFF0EFF8BC6C6E9981D71DA52E8EE92CC7BDD562DEDC8
3AF5B1BFFF5D4827FF1E052B0575E795B10DD83504
-# off=1730 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
+# off=2279 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
+:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 6052B2AD31A6631C
+       version 4, created 1510591057, md5len 0, sigclass 0x10
+       digest algo 2, begin of digest b8 b8
+       hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2017-11-13)
+       hashed subpkt 5 len 2 (trust signature of depth 1, value 120)
+       critical hashed subpkt 6 len 17 (regular expression: "<[^>]+[@.]none>$\0")
+       subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 6052B2AD31A6631C)
+       data: 302A23A15D9BE409F84A27045A23190D9ABDBC0C6AA5D00F339094189BC90F487891FD326014658665881E8AA3D94CE554425CE5F7D0FCB9BC5BADA79F32194B21A774A76FEBCBCAF8CD2D39A5147980FE5760556D2C2CC3D845BBF47CC815F1CD1933DDB9EA5CE1894F3A870D4E12020C6CC8CBC59DAEB0661AE496C9B55DC268D4392F7DD0CE85C3D60AE0B91574B1F97D161939C1B175C7030C32E8EFF6
8196D2CBC7C249312C6714EAA159E200E911C75FA1218F943E3740E30BDF419DB4E41B722B7C3347E7546D067936DD2D8FB30BA882361FAF8ED62173BA0B184DDDEFAB00F37FB44360B1EAF386C6B8E1F60F430C327CD3A892416D3A050B9636A39931E6BF7E2BB646B48DE3B862770CC3FB3A43F1B0709D04A190EDC9F44212300483BCDE95D961FFF026EA18053E967263AFE8875B44F0C20B8CC697A0A9CA32C3C2C12F3B
01E5BA669069CCD1990EA01546CA4109B2FC7299F7713C6DBCA1F92607BE7733D3AC21563C7D24773059B75C085B20DE6F269D8F8F2992969D8C1A0C610978D8E8CBA35741205576E9BF0489D9DB454DB6397FFC497EDBD04FC28D575458F5C382B431057C71EDFFE39DE55AF53368972D2D499B1F53A01296FF677D238E8DA59E36CB4A399F8AF842773A4D375FBD4800351CBA8C8A5596EDED3CDC0C5CF3C5AE019E51493E
4BC5C6216B0521EC1F2848ABC719CE587E7D562C9F
+# off=2845 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
+:signature packet: algo 1, keyid FBC07D6A97016CB3
+       version 4, created 1510591553, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
+       digest algo 10, begin of digest e1 d8
+       hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 94AA3A5BDBD40EA549CABAF9FBC07D6A97016CB3)
+       hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2017-11-13)
+       subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID FBC07D6A97016CB3)
+       data: 18A60F7E6F1F5CF9023A9976E93450BC5D5218421178982D8FB21ACC35ADB1EE440505CE4EE002D3878C744943C6F4DD3E42A46F2659BDF659707F6B795C04244337A87FE727614FE8279CAC44354A4CCE376185875C1FF283A5A7DADEE7D73BA381A3B2EFCDDB5017FFF53152370AD5635393A0329E5455B240B0D816C729DA72D9DFB1B54567DCAE180996BF57AE2C5F67CC06B8E7122F50BF4E74085804
140E5EF6E83AB6ADBB19606AD3289D778CE3A73CA026F96FCF73BB93173691B47FECE6DF68A655C987B5E130CEDB36A064021BDA3DB8D4B116A731B6C9BB17E87968B6B84D2A9CE5B7CF49ACB5F28691A515C332D365C39364964910299139EA184EE6E605CE10BEF6FFA6ECD3D7CDF83B9BB8E82EB3F35D03E0A554321F511F107D7317A8F819FFB954A86A5711AFB5EA765D30ABCC9BF24AC2FD701F9005C586F6B5575572
AA4D6682E0C8BEF6397307E06DCD95ED633B724D899B49761D584067AADB82092BEBAE95FA50B32FE18BDF383681F6D436738ADD935A7E85F43FC3DC0AABA663663AB6E6028179CC265429CBE067522976A7C112396187AAB771DE695972554D93CE08B91A317BA9B165820C40AED5FE4A677F8492CE990152144EF48A4DB5AADA74E66B0A40644B9929D0F7A4681522F11FD24FB2B31A45AACABD0A82D1F051D9970F3091A3
F94D2127378BE3F6DB57E2AB09BA938CC155A06554
+# off=3411 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
 :public sub key packet:
        version 4, algo 1, created 1384876967, expires 0
        pkey[0]: BA96EABBBEE2F1E9AE079CD5DB49C756B8D3F9B735729DE2AB021A90AFD004C34D8F379F6C75290D0E8BA67BB5FDBCA4A4EE545E677D88168BF67CCC172651E9B33F73B9A3927683D2C57AD1A30E5003B0137B325ED43E1A8FC9EDDB9A6D64D76CDF152A21004BEB980750C90EFC098C2363EEF8A3BBF2AF7812CB1D98947509505F345D9E7BA83C8D8066B2A242369433990B8984F2C4A88156DC77217
F64865F73836B14B615A47BF0E21FD5BA9759CA605931BF185E25326818B16A9C152B3E29CAFF74EC1FFB0A751F3E31F8140A410DFD209172CBDCCDA9CCA2018EE8ED3D19BDC5DE6B0B057DB416CE983123D7959488F2874B0095599C1C548DFC20A65C79A5AAA483ED58BF6A24D3DE8C1F31FB033782799BFA3727FAD018A3AE178C2CE32D69789A968B7DA69808A0D310732ADEB577A948F3207C19DCAB7A3A0361521E889
524AF780846C201132F2EB02225F06DD9292B17C2FE1DA48E2FC11BB7BCB0F3910A6633E16E1000D8CCAFE059410C900F6408948D2A2990AF8B852685A264298CB1CFE590361AF288267D6E920A9236BCDD51CC11E528F15E28DBF1E711456F33D960874F83FE5B67A75812A995E68395B39FEAFBFECE42C30FDFCE50C28C3BEFF205D2986D6E8DF487B122F6D7CBE991BFD59F4AAF701B437A7EB620D346E9D47D05D03E649
0047F00C2933720924453AA02C461C25B20032F96D2AB
        pkey[1]: 010001
        keyid: 5929664098F03378
-# off=2258 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=549
+# off=3939 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=549
+:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 47484E50656D16C7
+       version 4, created 1384876967, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
+       digest algo 2, begin of digest 19 58
+       hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2013-11-19)
+       hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
+       hashed subpkt 9 len 4 (key expires after 4y1d0h0m)
+       subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 47484E50656D16C7)
+       data: 5C08648D291E6DC03BC5F1B2384F318F687940E88818DF24069DBAF11579D8F174CC65752047B855BB17A84EC7792D79B95A2961C9D208455B528A3464AD40BA3CEB856C7A8EA1D2E8869302CAE9858BF1D555B5B4304C30AC5A32466F9A5F299989DD279071DB08EEE3F690390A81AA7F136CDE1BA121817A9F61ACF951934E751CAE9FD5926C2E25EC221C573A335D562900609A4344602D170E33BB68FB
02B5EC6262BCA3A2BC9FEC21470A773B7586942F007D669F0E9D98814AD497261DDC5870258E22B797429025C41BF467F1A2C639C4ED5491948082FC146DA539A91C67F7930E7A6F619C39031A6E8F6CC6404A2E6C71D136524A6E1613441472203A6D4B3F980A81D14715E5D849DE4E0E70232A7BF46DC116EC4E3BFBBC925FFB273E12CEA5B396E8AF97FC958C3955629FEE5F938A3326F5B2CB3433AFBA1E8E61DC4A81EC
54C7F94940B323718F04FBEE64AB8063089144E14BEA3370A94FB9C40C919A21EBECF473B3E44321E19609216A4A5CEF4A4F96582686683FFFBA115044E957FF6D3D9A8CA215EDABDE0F4F099FB8DC5FAECE7FD3E0346998ECCE112C4CC921601812B4333F28A3911380CB6BDB6A07802B5D9E343BBBDC7D023A3C49536FF9631E163D5777F5670F55BDA81C899269EB51677658B61043C44E2433C928F6142976A6D375095D
989DA093B7AB5D0AFD778FD86A2105FE6AD2299F53
+# off=4491 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=549
 :signature packet: algo 1, keyid 47484E50656D16C7
        version 4, created 1510590784, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
        digest algo 2, begin of digest bd 3a
```

Comment: Er, doesn't `--list-packets` already show exactly what those packets are?

Comment: It doesn't seem to show any information about what they are and why they are there.